# How to eval variables with jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, eval

I wish to append or prepend some html to the page.

Rather than my function going:

```
var action = 'prepend'; // may be prepend or append
var htmlStr = '<strong>text example</strong>';
var obj = $('#wrapExample');

if(action == 'prepend'){

    $(obj).prepend(htmlStr);

}else{

   $(obj).append(htmlStr);

}
```

Can I somehow eval the 'action' variable e.g.

```
eval('$(obj).' + action + '(' + htmlStr + ')');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for

```
$(obj)[action](htmlStr)
```

Saying `someobject["something"]` and `someobject.something` are equivalent in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `eval` you can use:

```
$(obj)[action](htmlStr);
```

The following are equivalent:

```
a.foo
a["foo"]
```

Therefore, when you have something like:

```
var property = "foo";
```

You can do:

```
a[property]
```

to programmatically access a property/method.

Also, since your `obj` variable is already a jQuery result, you can skip the additional `$`:

```
obj[action](htmlStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be
`eval('$(obj).' + action + '(htmlStr);');`